# If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, what is known about $2^{\aleph_1}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, cardinals

This means: if $V\models{\sf ZFC}$ in such a way that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, can $2^{\aleph_1}$ be anything it ought to be?

By the way, can $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ be considered the 'simplest' case of $\lnot{\sf CH}$ in some sense?

Comment: In case it’s not clear from the answer (though it probably is), the answer to your specific question is that if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2,$ it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_1}$ is any cardinal $\ge \aleph_2$ whose cofinality is $\ge\aleph_2$ (which is exactly the same thing we could say without the stipulation that $2^{\aleph_0}= \aleph_2$).

Comment: (And e.g. if we changed the assumption to $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{57}$, then $2^{\aleph_1}$ could be any cardinal $\ge \aleph_{57}$ whose cofinality is $\ge \aleph_2.$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of the continuum function on regular cardinals can be anything "not obviously contradictory". More precisely:

> Theorem (Easton): Let $\text{Reg}$ be the class of regular cardinals. Supose $F:\text{Reg}\to \text{OR}$ is a cardinal-valued function such that
>
> - $\kappa<\lambda \implies F(\kappa)\le F(\lambda)$
> - $\text{cf}(F(\kappa))>\kappa$ for every $\kappa\in \text{Reg}$.
>
> Then there is a model of ZFC such that $2^\kappa=F(\kappa)$ for every $\kappa\in \text{Reg}$.

The first restriction on $F$ is obvious, while the second one follows from König's lemma.

---

If $\neg CH$, then $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$ (because $2^{\aleph_0}\ge \aleph_1$ just follows from Cantor's Theorem), so $\aleph_2$ is the smallest possible value of the continuum under $\neg CH$. There are some axioms superseding ZFC which imply $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. The Proper Forcing Axiom is an example of this.

Comment: Even before Paul J. Cohen proved the independence of the continuum hypothesis, András Hajnal proved that, if $ZFC+2^{\aleph_0}\gt\aleph_1$ is consistent, then $ZFC+2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ is consistent. I first learned of this result from someone who misunderstood it and told me somebody had proved that the continuum is either $\aleph_1$ or $\aleph_2$.

Comment: @bof That is very interesting. I was not aware of that result, do you have a reference?

Comment: @bof Neat, I didn't know that! I presume it's just the following: if $V\models\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$, let $X$ be a sequence of distinct reals in $V$ of length $\omega_2$ and take $L[X]$. Right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It must have been from his dissertation, where he invented relative constructibility. So I guess it's in this publication, which I certainly never read, and don't have access to now as it is paywalled: Hajnal, A. On a consistency theorem connected with the generalized continuum problem. Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 12 (1961), 321–376.

Comment: to the asker note that the full Easton's theorem is a massive overkill, a two steps iteration of Cohen's forcing from a model of GCH is enough to show that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$+$2^{\aleph_1}=$anything sensible is consistent

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Why are you even iterating? Just take a product, that's even simpler.

Comment: @Asaf true, good point